# Getting all my family likes (fan pages) using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get the list of fan pages my family liked. I'm using:

```
SELECT uid, page_id, type FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid FROM family WHERE profile_id = me())
```

However, it doesn't give me the name of the page.
What can I do?

I get:

```
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": 100000920150807, 
      "page_id": 147629621952548, 
      "type": "SPORT"
    }, 
    {
      "uid": 1342682182, 
      "page_id": 175822015800898, 
      "type": "INTEREST"
    },...
```

Comment: Do you have the user_likes and friends_likes permissions?

Comment: Yes. I get data but not the name because the page_fan table doesn't contain the name

Comment: Just fetch the page details from the page FQL table or the Graph API - you already have the IDs if your query worked correctly

Comment: @Igy yes, I just wanted to know if there is another way to do it.

Comment: You could use a batch request to feed the results of that query into another one?

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from two tables at once with a multiquery:

```
{"family_page_likes":
    "SELECT uid, page_id, type FROM page_fan WHERE 
       uid IN (SELECT uid FROM family WHERE profile_id = me())",
 "page_names":
     "SELECT page_id, name, description FROM page WHERE 
        page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM #family_page_likes)"}
```